# Trying to install Moralis-admin-cli

Tags: json, visual-studio, installation, npm-install, moralis

I am trying to install the "moralis-admin-cli" program to make my account and I have to add it the path that the Terminal gave me so it will download in the proper directory.
I did have a problem where the cursor was but that has been overcome.
So when I type in the code as the tutorial tells this how the tutorial shows how to do it and this is the error:
C:\metadata-static-app>npm install -g moralis-admin-cli
'npm' is not recognized as an internal command, operable program or batch file.

I just need to find a way to install this moralis program in the "metadata-static-app" directory on my computer so I can move on to the next step.
Can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add node.js on your environment, the npm command will work!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).